# refreshing a form which sources queried data

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have an issue with a form of which it's record source is based on a query containing three joined tables.  I am trying to create a toggle type switch which updates a field in one of the underlying tables wich subsequently needs to show on the form.  The issue is that the field remains blank and does not update on the form until AFTER additional record goes through the same process. The issue seems to be with the refresh or requery. Below is my code where the field in the underlying table is updated in the last SQL update statement.

```
Private Sub cmdFlowType_Click()

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb

Dim strSql As String

    strSql = "Select * from tblDependencies02 "
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenDynaset)
    rs.MoveLast

If IsNull(Me.txtFlow) Then

    txtFlow = 1

End If

If txtFlow < rs.RecordCount Then
    txtFlow = txtFlow + 1

Else
    txtFlow = 1

End If

strSql = "UPDATE tblDependencies01 INNER JOIN tblDependencies02 ON tblDependencies01.Flow = tblDependencies02.[No] SET tblDependencies01.FlowDescription = [tblDependencies02].[Type]"
Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (strSql)

Me.Refresh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. A simple addition of a requery PRIOR to the SQL update

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb

Dim strSql As String

    strSql = "Select * from tblDependencies02 "
     Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenDynaset)
     rs.MoveLast


If IsNull(Me.txtFlow) Then

    txtFlow = 1

End If


If txtFlow < rs.RecordCount Then
    txtFlow = txtFlow + 1

Else
    txtFlow = 1

End If

Me.Requery


strSql = "UPDATE tblDependencies01 INNER JOIN tblDependencies02 ON tblDependencies01.Flow = tblDependencies02.[No] SET tblDependencies01.FlowDescription = [tblDependencies02].[Type]"
Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (strSql)

Me.txtFlowType.Requery
```